# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprt.lib' with specific project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I just updated my project from x86 to x64 in VS2010. However, now I'm getting the following error, which I can't quite figure out how to fix.

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprt.lib'
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Note that it works for other projects that are alrdy x64. Just not for this specific on which I changed from x86.

Comment: as suggested by the above question, the easiest way is to re-install Visual Studio

Comment: It works for other projects. Just not for this specific one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in project properties you must add the directory containing the 64 bit version of msvcptr.lib

Comment: And where would that be?

Comment: don't know where the library is installed on your computer, sorry! ;) you can try to search for it in your filesystem.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013 Express and I do not have any x64 configuration and yet I get this same linker error when trying to link with Python that I build also with x32 configuration. it turned out to be a missing semi-colon in my linker settings.